# Maximum number of connected components of a closed set in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

This question came to mind while solving a problem. How many connected components are possible for a closed set?

My attempt is like this. Suppose A is a closed set.
Case I, if all the connected components consists of more than one point then we can choose a rational from each connected component. Since connected components are disjoint so they are at most countable.

Case II, connected components are all singleton::: here again arises a question is there exists any closed set whose cardinality is continuum such that each connected components are singleton.

After that i am unable to proceed. Please give me hint about these two questions.

And what will happen for case III, if connected components are mixed with singleton and non singleton?

Comment: Look at the Cantor set for an example

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: (In principle there is also the case of a number of connected components strictly between $\aleph_0$ and continuum, but that cannot happen for closed sets)

Comment: This can't happen for any other set also. As there doesn't exist any set with cardinality strictly between N0 and c. Is not it?

Comment: That's known as the continuum hypothesis and it's independent of the usual axioms of set theory

Comment: Would you like to explain your statement?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).